# Can I use namespaced models with FactoryMuff?

Tags: php, testing, laravel-4

I'm working on a new Laravel 4 project which I'm developing with a test-driven approach. I was able to [test models like a boss](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models/) just fine when all of my models were in the global namespace. However, I like to namespace stuff. I added namespaces to all of my models and controllers, but now when I run `phpunit`, I'm getting `ErrorException: User Model is not an valid Class for FactoryMuff`.

I've tried specifying the namespaces in the `$factory` variable as defined in my model, for example:

```
public static $factory = array(
    'title' => 'string',
    'slug' => 'string',
    'content' => 'text',
    'author_id' => 'factory|\\Project\\Model\\User',
);
```

However I still get the same error. I've also tried specifying the namespaces in the actual test case itself, for example:

```
$user = FactoryMuff::create('\\Project\\Model\\User');
```

I still get the same error.

I've also attemted to add `use` statements to the tests and models to make sure that the appropriate models are available within the scope of the tests, but that didn't yield any results either.

### Question

Is it possible to use `FactoryMuff` with namespaced models; and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES**, it is possible to use namespaced models with `FactoryMuff`.

In addition to declaring the fully namespaced class in the `$factory` variable within the model **and** the `FactoryMuff::create()` argument, you must also use the full namespace of the model in the relationship declaration. For example:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Project\\Model\\Post');
}
```

And in the related model:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Project\\Model\\User');
}
```